# Conditioning of Normal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

If A is a normal matrix, then $AA^H = A^HA$. I have observed that normal matrices tend to have good conditioning. I was wondering if this was always the case? Are there any bounds on what the condition number could be?

Comment: What about matrices of the form $\pmatrix{c & 0\cr 0 & 1/c\cr}$ where $c$ is real and nonzero?